# Efficiently replace np.darray values with 1-dim np.darrays by logical rule?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binary, rgb

I want to replace np.darray values with 1d arrays, which represent RGB pixels.

For example:

```
array([[0.7, 0.2],
       [0.1, 0.4]])
```

convert, by rule array_value > 0.5, to

```
array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0]],
       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

**Is there more time-efficient method to do this than np.apply_along_axis?**

I can do it with np.apply_along_axis, but this method is rather slow:

```
values = np.array([[0.7, 0.2], 
                   [0.1, 0.4]])

pixel_0 = np.array([0, 0, 0])
pixel_1 = np.array([255, 255, 255])
replace_scalar_by_RGB_pixel = lambda x: pixel_1 if x > 0.5 else pixel_0

np.apply_along_axis(replace_scalar_by_RGB_pixel, 2, np.expand_dims(values, 2))

Output: 
array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0]],
       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is just an iteration over the other axes.  No speed improvements over explicit iteration.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for making it clear! I naively thought it to be vectorized operation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what `np.where` is for:

```
>>> np.where(values[...,None]>0.5,pixel_1,pixel_0)
array([[[255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution improves the computation speed by 150-200 times!

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean array indexing to create a new array with the intended shape and the replaced pixels like this:

```
values = np.array([[0.7, 0.2], [0.1, 0.4]])
pixel_0 = np.array([0, 0, 0])
pixel_1 = np.array([255, 255, 255])
shape = values.shape
output = np.zeros((shape[0], shape[1], 3))
output[values > 0.5] = pixel_1
output[values <= 0.5] = pixel_0
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution improves the computation speed by 100 times!
Please, replace "values < 0.5" by "values <= 0.5" to include case when value == 0.5

Comment: @IvanMikhnenkov no problem and yeah good point, I just updated that